# Where should I go in Yangon to buy computer parts / electronics?

Tags: electronic-items, myanmar

I own a [Microsoft Surface Pro 2](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/devices/surface-pro-2)  and I've forgotten my charger back home.

I'm currently in Yangon and was wondering if there's **an "electronics quarter" in town with a high density of computer parts / electronics stores where I might be able to find a replacement charger?** (Alternatively, a Microsoft store would do but I'm less hopeful of that.)

I'm guessing that's my best shot of finding a replacement as opposed to hunting down individual stores in a city I don't know...

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @Relaxed I had a friend who was flying in from Hong Kong and joining me on the trip to buy and bring one from HK - I reckoned it would be a lot easier to find there and she was indeed able to bring one! In Yangon - maybe I don't know the city well enough but there doesn't seem to be a place  that fits the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not much of a "quarter" but [this map](http://www.mygola.com/yangon-region-d1043077/electronics-store) suggests there's a few stores between the 5th and 11th wards, with more a little bit scattered around. [This](http://mm.wowcity.com/yangon/yangon/?what=electronic&map) listing suggests there's a few to be found in a block between 50th and 50th lower street, around Sule Pagoda, as far west as Bo Ywe Road.

Very few of these actually have websites (though some list a phone number), and a lot of them seem catered to cellphone accessories, but that should hopefully give you a place to start and narrow it down.